# Warning Message from cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I currently have code similar to the below.

```
set.seed(1)
library(glmnet)
matrix_example <- matrix(runif(100000), ncol = 50)
grid <- 10 ^ seq(20, -2, length = 500)
x <- matrix_example[, -1]
y <- matrix_example[, 1] %>%
  scale(center = TRUE, scale = FALSE) %>%
  as.matrix()
fit_cv_glmnet <- cv.glmnet(x, y, lambda = grid, alpha = 1)
fit_glmnet <- glmnet(x, y, lambda = grid, alpha = 1)
```

When I run `cv.glmnet`, however, I get the following warning messages

```
Warning messages:
1: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
2: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
3: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
4: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
5: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
6: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
7: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
8: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
9: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
10: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

When I run `glmnet`, I do not get this message at all. Is there a reason why I am getting the warning with `cv.glmnet`? Does it have to do with the way that the function calculates the cross-validation error? As I said, the `glmnet` function works fine and I am able to identify a lambda whose model corresponds to the minimum BIC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the user-supplied lambda sequence tripping up the algorithm. This sequence is producing the same results/error for each lambda (as seen in the `cvm` vector in the `cv.glmnet` object).

If you need a user-supplied sequence, I'd suggest guiding the algorithm to create it using the `nlambda` and `lambda.min.ratio` arguments in your call to the function. Something like the below, changing the parameters to suit your purposes.

```
cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, nlambda = 500, lambda.min.ratio = 10^(-2))
```

For what it's worth, the warning message itself is related to an internally called `stats::regularize.values` function, itself called from an `approx` function. It seems to be a symptom of the issue with the lambda sequence, not a problem in and of itself.

Comment: Does the `stats::regularize.values` warning not exist with the `glmnet` function? Oddly, I was able to produce similar results by inputting `lambda=10^seq(-2, 10, by = 0.02)` into the `lambda` call for `cv.glmnet`.

Comment: We would need to read the source code more thoroughly, but I think it has to do with combining the individual `glmnet` calls within `cv.glmnet`. And yes, I don't think this affects your results. They should be valid regardless of this warning.